# Where does the iOS Photos app store user-entered captions?

Tags: ios, photos, metadata

I understand that the ability to add captions to photos was added in iOS 14. Where are these captions stored? For example, are they embedded into the .HEIC file as EXIF or XMP or IPTC metadata? Or a sidecar file? Or just in the Photos database?

If I transfer the photos to another device, how should I ensure the captions are transferred too?